# Pandas DataFrame: replace column values in one df with column values from another df in case of only certain string characters should be replaced

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I'm trying to replace column values in dataframe_1 with values from another column in the dataframe_2.
For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['animal', 'animal', 'animal'], 'col2': [0, 1, 2]}).set_index('col2')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat'], 'col2': [0, 2, 1]}).set_index('col2')
```

df1:

```
        col1
col2        
0     animal
1     animal
2     animal
```

df2:

```
      col1
col2     
0     cat
2     dog
1     cat
```

In this case after this command:

```
df1['col1'] = df2['col1']
```

I got this:

```
     col1
col2     
0     cat
1     cat
2     dog
```

It's work fine. But what should I do, if I want this changes for the certain string character in my column?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['animal id_0', 'animal id_1', 'animal id_2'], 'col2': [0, 1, 2]}).set_index('col2')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat'], 'col2': [0, 2, 1]}).set_index('col2')
```

I believe I can get something like this:

```
            col1
col2          
0     animal cat
1     animal cat
2     animal dog
```

With this line (and with attempt to do something like mapping, lol):

```
df1['col1'] = df1['col1'].str.replace(r'\d', df2['col1'], regex=True)
```

But it seems that it isn't as easy as it seems at first glance. Maybe you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are two components to your problem:

1. you have integer keys in `df1` that map to specific animal strings in `df2` (e.g. `0 = 'cat', 1 = 'cat', 2 = 'dog'`, etc)
2. those integer keys are embedded in a string and need to be extracted somehow (you need to pull the `1` out of `'animal 1'`)

There is a one liner solution, **though the below assumes you only ever have a single digit key to capture from each string in `df['col1']`**:

```
>>>df1['col1'].str.replace('(\d)',lambda x: df2['col1'].to_dict()[int(x.group(0))])
col2
0    animal cat
1    animal dog
2    animal cat
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

There's three things going on here:

`df['col1'].str.replace('(\d)',...)` is regex capturing those digits and passing them as a usable argument to the replacement side of the function (see [pd.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for more info)

`df2['col1'].to_dict()` is turning the implicit mapping defined in `df2` into an actual map, in the form of a `dict` with integer keys taken from the index of `df2`. You could also write something similar with the `.loc` accessor.

```
>>> df2['col1'].to_dict()
{0: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 1: 'cat'}
```

Lastly, `lambda x: df2['col1'].to_dict()[int(x.group(0))]` turns that map into a function that takes your capture group `x`, pulls the first (and only, in this case) captured group from it, casts it from `str` to `int` and then passes it through our map. Pandas' str.replace function allows callables like this as a valid `repl` when used with a regex capture pattern.

Comment: Thanks you a lot. It was really helpful!
I have another question for another case, but I'm not sure that it's worth a separate topic for it. If you have time for it of course.

Now I'm trying do something like this:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aa1:0bb', 'dd2:00cc', 'ff99:00hh', 'll3:0kk']})
df[column].str.replace('(\d+:\d+)', lambda x: df.index.to_dict()[x.group(0)])`

By this I mean that I want to replace pattern with its own index, but I get `Nan` instead. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two dataframes by index and then using `.apply` to replace `_` with correct value:

```py
x = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
x["col1_x"] = x.apply(lambda x: x["col1_x"].replace("_", x["col1_y"]), axis=1)
x = x.rename(columns={"col1_x": "col1"})

print(x[["col1"]])
```

Prints:

```
            col1
col2            
0     animal cat
1     animal cat
2     animal dog
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks for the quick answer. If you don't mind, I have an another question. I supposed that I need to do my changes by REGex, as in another task I have this case: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['animal id_0', 'animal id_1', 'animal id_2'], 'col2': [0, 1, 2]}).set_index('col2')`. Like every animal has its own id. So need to edit my question. Sorry for it.